# How to make sound within a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, audio

What I want to do is when the user refreshes the page, either the red, blue, green or yellow buttons will be animated and the sound will be played. Although the animation works, the sound doesn't. I tried using the basic var green = new Audio("sounds/green.mp3"); and green.play(); but no sound appears

JavaScript

```
let buttonColours =  ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
let gamePattern = [];

function nextSequence() {
  var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random()*3);
  return randomNumber;
}

var randomColor = buttonColours[nextSequence()];
animateButton();
gamePattern.splice(0,0,randomColor);

function animateButton() {
  if (randomColor=="green"){
    $("#green").css("opacity", "0.6");
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("#green").css("opacity", "1");
    }, 100);
    var green = new Audio("sounds/green.mp3");
    green.play();
  }
  if (randomColor=="blue"){
    $("#blue").css("opacity", "0.6");
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("#blue").css("opacity", "1");
    }, 100);
    var blue = new Audio("sounds/blue.mp3");
    blue.play();
  }
  if (randomColor=="red"){
    $("#red").css("opacity", "0.6");
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("#red").css("opacity", "1");
    }, 100);
    var red = new Audio("sounds/red.mp3");
    red.play();
  }
  if (randomColor=="yellow"){
    $("#yellow").css("opacity", "0.6");
    setTimeout(function() {
    $("#yellow").css("opacity", "1");
    }, 100);
    var yellow = new Audio("sounds/yellow.mp3");
    yellow.play();
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green"></div>
      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow"></div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src = "game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36662215/html-audio-element-not-playing-on-first-time

Comment: It might be a tough problem to solve if the code runs in a Chromium-based browser. See for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930680/how-to-handle-uncaught-in-promise-domexception-play-failed-because-the-use

Comment: I'm pretty sure that sound doesn't play until the user interacts with the page. Have you clicked on the page itself before reloading?

Comment: For that one, they have an event listener (button). In my case, when the user refreshes the page, the action happens. But thanks still. I will have a deeper look at it.

Comment: Yeah i did click on the page before reloading, still nothing

Comment: Check for a `NotAllowedError`. See exceptions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play).